# Add Custom Validation Annotation for a Parameter in Controller - JSR-303

Tags: spring-boot, bean-validation

I can't figure out how to resolve the following use case in Spring Boot. Indeed, I have a Spring Boot Rest Api (eg: `user-api`) with the following controller method with a custom validator for a parameter :

```
@PostMapping
   public User createUser(@ValidZipCode @RequestBody @Valid User user){
       return userService.saveUser(user);
   }
```

The `User` Class is defined in an external dependency (eg: `user-model`). It has the following fields :

```
public class User {
   @NotNull
   private String firstName;
   @NotNull
   private String lastName;
   private String zipCode;
   // getters, setters ..
}
```

In, `user-api` I created the following custom annotation :

```
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = ZipCodeValidator.class)
public @interface ValidZipCode {

    String message() default "Must be a valid zipCode. Found: ${validatedValue}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

And so the `ZipCodeValidator` implementation :

```
public class ZipCodeValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidZipCode, User> {
private ZipCodeService zipCodeService;

@Override
public void initialize(ValidZipCode constraintAnnotation) { }

@Override
public boolean isValid(User user, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
    return !Objects.isNull(user.getZipCode()) ?
            zipCodeService.isValidZipCode(user.getZipCode()) :
            false;
}
```

NB: `zipCodeService.isValidZipCode()` is a simple `boolean` method.

The problem is that when I call the endpoint it never access the `@ValidZipCode` annotation. Is there any `bean` configuration to set up to make it works ?

Thks for your help ;)

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @cassiomolin for his answer. Indeed, when I annotate the controller class with `@Validated` It works :D

I Hope this post will help other devs ;)

Comment: Thanks for the excellent explanation. One more thing: one needs to add the `spring-boot-starter-validation` dependency to pom.xml. Spring won't complain if you don't, but custom validation classes will just be ignored. Took me some time to figure it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ensure that your controller class is annotated with [`@Validated`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/annotation/Validated.html).

See the following quote from the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#validation-beanvalidation):

> To be eligible for Spring-driven method validation, all target classes need to be annotated with Spring’s `@Validated` annotation [...]

Comment: Exactly what I needed ! It works perfectly now ! :D