# Springboot custom validation jsr 303 is not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-annotations

I was trying to add custom annotation validation on the age field. as I saw some JSR 303 topics

Controller

```
@Validated
@Controller
public class StudentController {

    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository repository;

    @PostMapping("/send")
    public ResponseEntity saveStudent(@AgeValidator @RequestBody Student student) {
        System.out.println("saveStudent invoked");
        repository.save(student);
        ResponseData responseData = new ResponseData();
        responseData.setResultId("result");
        responseData.setResultValue("saved");
        ResponseEntity entity = new ResponseEntity(responseData, HttpStatus.OK);
        return entity;
    }
}
```

Model

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Student {

    @Id
    @Column(length = 7)
    private String Id;
    private String fullName;
    private Integer age;
    private String department;

}
```

AgeValidator

```
package com.example.demo4;
import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;
@Documented
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = AgeValidatorImpl.class)
public @interface AgeValidator {
    String message()
            default "Please enter a valid age";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

AgeValidatorImpl

```
class AgeValidatorImpl implements ConstraintValidator<AgeValidator, Student> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(AgeValidator constraintAnnotation) {
        ConstraintValidator.super.initialize(constraintAnnotation); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Student t, ConstraintValidatorContext cvc) {
        System.out.println("AgeValidatorImpl invoked");
        if (t.getAge() < 18) {
            return false;
        } else if (t.getAge() > 40) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

so if am sending using postman at any age it saves the record and it's not validating. I saw many peoples commented to add annotation on controller **@validated** which I import from *import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated*. Still Why this is not working. what am missing?

Comment: Your `@AgeValidator` should be on the `age` field or the class, not the method argument. The method argument should be annotated with `@Valid`.

Comment: @M.Deinum I did that but If I write at AgeValidator I am getting the error "annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration" though I changed class AgeValidatorImpl implements ConstraintValidator<AgeValidator, Integer> { this also.

Comment: @M.Deinum I was trying to achieve something like this reference. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60432760/add-custom-validation-annotation-for-a-parameter-in-controller-jsr-303#

Comment: You should use `@Target({ElementType.FIELD})`.

Comment: @JoãoDias I tried that but still not working.

Comment: You shouldn't do what is in that link, as that is for a different purpose. Either annotate your student class with that annotation (and make it work for types) or the field.

Comment: I have added my work on github can you see and check am I did everything right.?https://github.com/lakadbagha/democustomannotationvalidation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this,

I have updated `@Age` annotation. You can provide upper and lower limit for validation. Note I that have added `ElementType.FIELD` to `@Target`. It allows you to use this in class fields as well.

```
@Documented
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = AgeValidator.class)
public @interface Age {
    int lower() default 14;
    int upper() default 60;
    String message() default "Please enter a valid age";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

This is the validation constrain for the annotation.

```
public class AgeValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Age, Integer> {

    private int upperLimit;
    private int lowerLimit;

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Integer i, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        return lowerLimit < i && i < upperLimit;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(Age constraintAnnotation) {
        this.lowerLimit = constraintAnnotation.lower();
        this.upperLimit = constraintAnnotation.upper();
    }
}
```

You can pass the annotation to class fields and override the upper and lower limit.

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Student {

    @Id
    @Column(length = 7)
    private String Id;
    private String fullName;
    @Age(lower = 10, upper = 70)
    private Integer age;
    private String department;

}
```

Used `@Validated` annotation to validate the `Student` object against all the validation constraints.

```
@PostMapping("/send")
    public ResponseEntity saveStudent(@Validated @RequestBody Student student)
```

#### Update

Replace this dependency,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

by this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: it's not working still. I committed my work on GitHub can you see it? https://github.com/lakadbagha/democustomannotationvalidation

Comment: @DEEPAKMAURYA find my update. This will resolve your issue

Comment: yes, that library file dependency was the main issue. Thank you so much.

Comment: is there any way to throw an error like if age is less than condition then throw LessAgeException if age is bigger then throw OverAgeException which have error message?

Comment: When we validate fields like this, spring will throw `MethodArgumentNotValidException` if there any invalid fields. We can catch this exception using `ControllerAdvice` then we can throw our custom exception. Please note that `MethodArgumentNotValidException` exception contain details about all the invalid fields. Here some references [ref1](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-validation-message-interpolation), [ref2](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)